# How to change text on hover and revert to default on mouse out?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a div which shows count like this:

How can I change the text from 0 to any word for example, when mouse is over the div, and revert to 0 when mouse leaves.

I tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
$('.post-fav a').bind('mouseenter',function() {
    var default_text = $(this).text();
    $(this).css({'background-position' : 'left bottom', 'color' : '#1871a4'});
    $(this).html('<?php _e('favorite','deluxe'); ?>');
});
$('.post-fav a').bind('mouseleave',function() {
    $(this).css({'background-position' : 'left top', 'color' : '#666'});
    $(this).text(default_text);
});
```

The default text is variable, each element has specific count, I need someway to store the initial count when mouse moves over ..I can't hard code it in js as 0 or any other count.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and a jsfiddle?

Comment: No need to put single quotes around the PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use the hover function, the first parameter is mouseover, the second is mouseout:

```
$('div').hover(
    function() { $(this).html('anyword'); },
    function() { $(this).html('0'); }
);
```

**EDIT:**

```
var storedtext;
$('div').hover(
    function() { 
        storedtext = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('anyword'); 
    },
    function() { $(this).html(storedtext); }
);
```

Comment: The default text is not always 0. I just want it to revert to whatever value was inside the element when mouse moved over it.

Comment: Ah okay, than you just need to store the old text inside a variable in first function and use it in the second, I will update my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$inittext=$('div').html;
```

and then as Shogun said

```
$('div').hover(
function() { $(this).html('anyword'); },
function() { $(this).html($inittext); }
);
```

Comment: I think I didn't make it clear. I have tons and tons of these divs. I can't set one initial value.

Comment: Why dont you make inittext a global variable, change its value to whatever is the divs html when you hover in and change it back to inittext when you hover out

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to it with a data attribute:

```
<div data-initial-value="0">
<script>
$('div').bind('mouseenter',function() {
  var default_text = $(this).text();
  $(this).css({'background-position' : 'left bottom', 'color' : '#1871a4'});
  $(this).html('<?php _e('favorite','deluxe'); ?>');
});
$('div').bind('mouseleave',function() {
  $(this).css({'background-position' : 'left top', 'color' : '#666'});
  $(this).text($(this).data('initialValue');
}); 
</script>
```